# pandas, dataframe, groupby, std

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

New to pandas here. A (trivial) problem: hosts, operations, execution times. I want to group by host, then by host+operation, calculate std deviation for execution time per host, then by host+operation pair. Seems simple?

It works for grouping by a single column:

```
df
Out[360]:
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 132564 entries, 0 to 132563
Data columns (total 9 columns):
datespecial    132564  non-null values
host           132564  non-null values
idnum          132564  non-null values
operation      132564  non-null values
time           132564  non-null values
...
dtypes: float32(1), int64(2), object(6)



byhost = df.groupby('host')


byhost.std()
Out[362]:
                 datespecial         idnum      time
host
ahost1.test  11946.961952  40367.033852  0.003699
host1.test   15484.975077  38206.578115  0.008800
host10.test           NaN  37644.137631  0.018001
...
```

Nice. Now:

```
byhostandop = df.groupby(['host', 'operation'])

byhostandop.std()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-364-2c2566b866c4> in <module>()
----> 1 byhostandop.std()

/home/username/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.pyc in std(self, ddof)
    386         # todo, implement at cython level?
    387         if ddof == 1:
--> 388             return self._cython_agg_general('std')
    389         else:
    390             f = lambda x: x.std(ddof=ddof)

/home/username/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.pyc in _cython_agg_general(self, how, numeric_only)
   1615
   1616     def _cython_agg_general(self, how, numeric_only=True):
-> 1617         new_blocks = self._cython_agg_blocks(how, numeric_only=numeric_only)
   1618         return self._wrap_agged_blocks(new_blocks)
   1619

/home/username/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.pyc in _cython_agg_blocks(self, how, numeric_only)
   1653                 values = com.ensure_float(values)
   1654
-> 1655             result, _ = self.grouper.aggregate(values, how, axis=agg_axis)
   1656
   1657             # see if we can cast the block back to the original dtype

/home/username/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.pyc in aggregate(self, values, how, axis)
    838                 if is_numeric:
    839                     result = lib.row_bool_subset(result,
--> 840                                                  (counts > 0).view(np.uint8))
    841                 else:
    842                     result = lib.row_bool_subset_object(result,

/home/username/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/lib.so in pandas.lib.row_bool_subset (pandas/lib.c:16540)()

ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'float64_t' but got 'float'
```

Huh?? Why do I get this exception?

More questions:

- how do I calculate std deviation on `dataframe.groupby([several columns])`?
- how can I limit calculation to a selected column? E.g. it obviously doesn't make sense to calculate std dev on dates/timestamps here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's important to know your version of Pandas / Python. Looks like this exception could arise  in Pandas version < 0.10 (see [ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'float64_t' but got 'float'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14984667/valueerror-buffer-dtype-mismatch-expected-float64-t-but-got-float)). To avoid this, you can cast your `float` columns to `float64`:

```
df.astype('float64')
```

To calculate `std()` on selected columns, just select columns :)

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a':range(10), 'b':range(10,20), 'c':list('abcdefghij'), 'g':[1]*3 + [2]*3 + [3]*4})
>>> df
   a   b  c  g
0  0  10  a  1
1  1  11  b  1
2  2  12  c  1
3  3  13  d  2
4  4  14  e  2
5  5  15  f  2
6  6  16  g  3
7  7  17  h  3
8  8  18  i  3
9  9  19  j  3
>>> df.groupby('g')[['a', 'b']].std()
          a         b
g                    
1  1.000000  1.000000
2  1.000000  1.000000
3  1.290994  1.290994
```

#### update

As far as it goes, it looks like `std()` is calling `aggregation()` on the `groupby` result, and a subtle bug (see here - [Python Pandas: Using Aggregate vs Apply to define new columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279188/python-pandas-using-aggregate-vs-apply-to-define-new-columns)). To avoid this, you can use `apply()`:

```
byhostandop['time'].apply(lambda x: x.std())
```

Comment: pip freeze shows pandas==0.12.0. I'm using "Anaconda" distribution, downloaded yesterday.

Comment: `byhostandop['time'].std()` again raises the same exception.

Comment: just out of curiosuty, have you tried `byhostandop['time'].apply(lambda x:x.std())`?

Comment: `byhostandop['time'].apply(lambda x: x.std())` WORKS. Thank you!

Comment: In `df.astype` reply, did you mean that I should explicitly convert column type? Like this works: `df['time'] = df['time'].astype('float64'); byhostandop=df.groupby(['host', 'operation']); byhostandop['time'].std()`. But I'm not sure if this is idiomatic pandas operation or I would better do smth else to get correct (float64) type in column for std dev calculation.

Comment: The error ```ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'float64_t'  but got 'float'``` for `np.Float32` data persists in pandas 0.13.0. The temporary solution: ```grouped = df.astype(np.float64).groupby(...)``` (assuming all the data is float)