# Why is pandas.Series.std() different from numpy.std()?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, statistics

This is what I am trying to explain:

```
>>> a = pd.Series([7, 20, 22, 22])
>>> a.std()
7.2284161474004804
>>> np.std(a)
6.2599920127744575
```

---

I have data about many different restaurants. For simplicity I have extracted just one restaurant with four items:

```
>>> df
    restaurant_id  price
id                      
1           10407      7
3           10407     20
6           10407     22
13          10407     22
```

For each restaurant, I want to get the standard deviation, however, Pandas **returns wrong values**.

```
>>> df.groupby('restaurant_id').std()
                  price
restaurant_id          
10407          7.228416
```

We can get the correct value with `np.std()`:

```
>>> np.std(df['price'])
6.2599920127744575
```

But obviously, this is not a solution when I have more than one restaurant. How do I do this properly?

---

Just to make sure, I checked that `df['price'].mean() == np.mean(df['price'])`.

There is a related discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20350863/pandas-dataframe-groupby-std), but their suggestions do not work either.

Comment: `pd.Series([7,20,22,22]).std(ddof=0)` would be the same number as `np.std`

Comment: OK, resolved. I guess I have to think, which one I want to use.

Comment: FWIW, I wanted to mention `.agg(np.std)` as a workaround (which wouldn't be an ideal solution in this case, but the pattern is good to know), but actually, that still produces the Bessel output! I had to do `.agg(lambda col: np.std(col))` to get the non-Bessel output. I'm not an expert on this, but I think `np.std` is a ufunc, which causes special behaviour.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Pandas [std](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.std.html) is using [Bessel's correction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel%27s_correction) by default -- that is, the standard deviation formula with `N-1` instead of `N` in the denominator. To use `N-0`:

```
a.std(ddof=0) == np.std(a)
```