# Pandas agg function gives different results for numpy std vs nanstd

Tags: python, pandas

I'm converting some numpy code to use pandas `DataFrame`. The data potentially contains NaN values, so I make use of numpy's nan functions such as `nanstd` in the original code. I was of the impression that pandas skips NaN values by default, so I switched to using the regular versions of the same functions.

I want to group the data and compute some statistics on it using `agg()`, however when I use `np.std()` I am getting different results to the original code, even in cases where the data doesn't contain any NaNs

Here's a small example demonstrating the problem

```
>>> arr = np.array([[1.17136, 1.11816],
                    [1.13096, 1.04134],
                    [1.13865, 1.03414],
                    [1.09053, 0.96330],
                    [1.02455, 0.94728],
                    [1.18182, 1.04950],
                    [1.09620, 1.06686]])

>>> df = pd.DataFrame(arr, 
                      index=['foo']*3 + ['bar']*4, 
                      columns=['A', 'B'])

>>> df
           A        B
foo  1.17136  1.11816
foo  1.13096  1.04134
foo  1.13865  1.03414
bar  1.09053  0.96330
bar  1.02455  0.94728
bar  1.18182  1.04950
bar  1.09620  1.06686

>>> g = df.groupby(df.index)

>>> g['A'].agg([np.mean, np.median, np.std])
         mean    median       std
bar  1.098275  1.093365  0.064497
foo  1.146990  1.138650  0.021452

>>> g['A'].agg([np.mean, np.median, np.nanstd])
         mean    median    nanstd
bar  1.098275  1.093365  0.055856
foo  1.146990  1.138650  0.017516
```

If I compute the std values with the numpy functions, I get the expected result in both cases. What's going on inside the `agg()` function?

```
>>> np.std(df.loc['foo', 'A'])
0.01751583474079002
>>> np.nanstd(df.loc['foo', 'A'])
0.017515834740790021
```

---

***Edit:***

As mentioned in the answer linked by Vivek Harikrishnan, pandas uses a different method to compute the std. This seems to match my results

```
>>> g['A'].agg(['mean', 'median', 'std'])
         mean    median       std
bar  1.098275  1.093365  0.064497
foo  1.146990  1.138650  0.021452
```

And if I specify a lambda that calls `np.std()` I get the expected result

```
>>> g['A'].agg([np.mean, np.median, lambda x: np.std(x)])
         mean    median  <lambda>
bar  1.098275  1.093365  0.055856
foo  1.146990  1.138650  0.017516
```

This suggests that the pandas functions are being called instead when I write `g['A'].agg([np.mean, np.median, np.std])`. The question is why does this happen when I explicitly tell it to use the numpy functions?

Comment: Possibly here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25695986/pandas-why-pandas-series-std-is-different-from-numpy-std

Comment: I understand that pandas computes std differently, but that doesn't explain why I get a different result when I specify `np.std`. I am not calling the pandas version

Answer (score 11):

It seems that Pandas either replaces `np.std` in the `.agg([np.mean, np.median, np.std])` call with the built-in Pandas `Series.std()` method or calls `np.std(series, ddof=1)`:

```
In [337]: g['A'].agg([np.mean, np.median, np.std, lambda x: np.std(x)])
Out[337]:
         mean    median       std  <lambda>
bar  1.098275  1.093365  0.064497  0.055856
foo  1.146990  1.138650  0.021452  0.017516
```

NOTE: pay attention that `np.std` and `lambda x: np.std(x)` producing different results.

if we specify `ddof=1` (Pandas default) explicitly, then we will have the same result:

```
In [338]: g['A'].agg([np.mean, np.median, np.std, lambda x: np.std(x, ddof=1)])
Out[338]:
         mean    median       std  <lambda>
bar  1.098275  1.093365  0.064497  0.064497
foo  1.146990  1.138650  0.021452  0.021452
```

using built-in `'std'` produces the same result:

```
In [341]: g['A'].agg([np.mean, np.median, 'std', lambda x: np.std(x, ddof=1)])
Out[341]:
         mean    median       std  <lambda>
bar  1.098275  1.093365  0.064497  0.064497
foo  1.146990  1.138650  0.021452  0.021452
```

---

The second rule of Python Zen says it all:

```
In [340]: import this
The Zen of Python, by Tim Peters

Beautiful is better than ugly.
Explicit is better than implicit.  # <----------- NOTE !!!
Simple is better than complex.
Complex is better than complicated.
Flat is better than nested.
Sparse is better than dense.
Readability counts.
Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.
Although practicality beats purity.
Errors should never pass silently.
Unless explicitly silenced.
In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess.
There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.
Although that way may not be obvious at first unless you're Dutch.
Now is better than never.
Although never is often better than *right* now.
If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea.
If the implementation is easy to explain, it may be a good idea.
Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!
```

Comment: Yeah, I came to the same conclusion. That's what I was trying to illustrate by using `lambda x: np.std(x)`. I'd still like to know why this is happening

Comment: @user3419537 or MaxU: Should we consider this behavior a bug? Silently changing the default behavior of function specified by a user is exactly the kind of oversight that leads to massive paper retractions across an entire field. I've found https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/18734, which is related, but slightly different.

Comment: Never mind. Apparently this is a `wontfix` "feature". https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/13344

Comment: @Tashus It seems there is hope.  With Pandas 2.1.1 I get this warning: "FutureWarning: The provided callable <function nanstd at ...> is currently using SeriesGroupBy.std. In a future version of pandas, the provided callable will be used directly. To keep current behavior pass the string "std" instead."

Comment: Note that using the `lambda` wrapper seems to have a strong performance impact. Would it prevent vectorization of numpy/pandas?